# Expected Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to get the result from the below table like this ...,

Expected result :

```
Fldempployee           flddept       Date          Day          Week off 
00625267-Karthick S    Corporate     04-25-2012    Wednesday
                             (or)
00625267-Karthick S    Corporate     04-28-2012    Saturday     Week end
                             (or)
00625267-Karthick S    Corporate     04-29-2012    sunday    Week end
                             (or)
00625267-Karthick S    Corporate     04-27-2012    Friday
```

My Table structure like this.

```
F_id    flddept     fldemployee         fldintime   fldouttime  fldlateafter    fldearlybefore  fldweekoff  fldshiftname        fldassigndate   fldfromdate fldtodate   fldrefid
1       Corporate   00625267-Karthick S 09:30 am    06:15 pm    09:30 am        06:15 pm        Sat,Sun,    COR-General Shift      04-25-2012   04-01-2012  05-31-2012
```

In  fldweekoff column have two values sat and sunday.It may be Mon and wednesday.I want to search a record for a specific date means the above one record displayed like that with the week off field.The specific date is not in week off means it should displayed null value..'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

SELECT Fldempployee,flddept,fldassigndate AS date,DAYNAME(fldassigndate) as day,
if(SUBSTRING(DAYNAME(date),1,1)='S','weekend','weekdays') as week-off from your_tableName;

HERE  :  the day/week-off column is displayed based on the 'fldassigndate' column.if you give the fldassigndate(04-25-2012) means it will give you result like this.

Fldempployee------flddept-------Date--------Day-------Week-off 
00625267-Karthick S    Corporate     04-25-2012    Wednesday    weekdays 
otherwise please post your query
Cheers

Comment: suppose i want to get the result set from 04-01-2012 to 04-10-2012. how can i get this list with the specific week end.

Comment: No problem..!Here the query works based on the fldassigndate column.If the date is available with in your range it will show you the result..

Comment: But it returns week off for the all rows. not only for the specific date.

Comment: select * from (SELECT Fldemployee,flddept,fldassigndate AS fasdfdate,
fldfromdate,fldtodate,
DAYNAME(fldassigndate) as day,
if(SUBSTRING(DAYNAME(fldassigndate),1,8)='Sat,Sun,','weekend','weekdays') as weekoff 
from tblattendancesetup where fldemployee='00625267-Karthick S')u4)ewr  on cal.date between DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ewr.fldfromdate,'%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')and DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ewr.fldtodate,'%m-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')